# Copy output of curl to file

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, curl

I'm running raspbian and using this bash script to take a photo every minute and upload it to my FTP server:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
 DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S")
 raspistill -q 10 -th none -o /home/pi/fb/$DATE.jpg
 curl -T /home/pi/fb/$DATE.jpg  ftp://myftpserver --user myuser:mypass >> /home/pi/fb/log.txt
 sleep 60
 echo finished $DATE >> /home/pi/fb/log.txt
done
```

I want the output of `curl` to appear in the `log.txt` file but it is always printed to the console. Why is that? I also tried to use `tee` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

curl prints its status to stderr rather than stdout. To capture stderr in the same file, you need to redirect stderr to stdout by adding `2>&1` **AFTER** your stdout redirection:

```
curl -T /home/pi/fb/$DATE.jpg  ftp://myftpserver --user myuser:mypass >> /home/pi/fb/log.txt 2>&1
```

For a thought-provoking question that will help you understand stdout and stderr better... why must the `2>&1` be after the initial `>>` instead of before?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing output for standard error (stderr) which is a separate stream from standard out (stdout).

It can be redirected with 2>&1 after the output destination.

For Example:

$ curl -T /home/pi/fb/$DATE.jpg  ftp://myftpserver --user myuser:mypass >> /home/pi/fb/log.txt 2>&1

Comment: Note that while you were on the right track, you've fallen victim to the ol' redirect-stderr-first blunder. Why do you think that doesn't work?